# No result on the screen

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web

This code is not working on React `localhost 3000`. I've tried many ways.

```
class Counter extends Component {
    state={
        counters:[
            {id : 1, value: 0},
            {id : 1, value: 0},
            {id : 1, value: 0},
            {id : 1, value: 0},
            {id : 1, value: 0}
        ]
    };

    render() {
        return (
        <div> 
            {this.state.counters.map(counter => <Counter key={counter.id}/>)}
        </div>
    )};
}

export default Counter;
```

I've tried to run the code many times but it didn't work.

I've face this problem many times and start the page again and it work but this time no answer.

Comment: This will recursively render `Counter`s forever.

Comment: shouldn't state be initialized in constructor, and is this recursive component to render same counter component for each item in counters array? will just be infinite recursion no?

Comment: you should familiarise yourself with the browsers developer console - I'm sure there'd be errors shown there

Answer (score -1):

you should rename the current class to "Counters" (or something appropiate for the parent of all the counters) and in another file create a class called Counter that renders only one element representing a Counter.

As explained in the comments, rendering  elements within a Counter class generates a recursive loop, which is why it doesn't show anything. This problem is solved if you render the Counter elements in another class.

As is, for each Counter you try to render the program is trying to render 5 different counters.